# Why storm replays tuple from spout instead of retry on crashing component?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am using storm to process online problems, but I cant't understand why storm replays tuple from spout . Retrying on what crashed may be  more effective than replaying from root, right?
Anyone can help me? Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A typical spout implementation will replay only the `FAILED` tuples. As explained [here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Guaranteeing-message-processing) a tuple emitted from the spout can trigger thousands of others tuple and storm creates a tree of tuple based on that. Now a tuple is called "fully processed" when every message in the tree has been processed. While emitting spout add a `message id` which is used to identify the tuple in later phase. This is called anchoring and can be done in the following way

```
    _collector.emit(new Values("field1", "field2", 3) , msgId);
```

Now from the link posted above it says

> A tuple is considered failed when its tree of messages fails to be fully processed **within a specified timeout**. This timeout can be configured on a topology-specific basis using the Config.TOPOLOGY_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECS configuration and defaults to 30 seconds.

If the tuple times-out Storm will call the `FAIL` method on spout and likewise in case of success the `ACK` method will be called.

So at this point storm will let you know which are the tuple that it  has been failed to process but if you look into the source code you will see that the implementation of the `fail` method is empty in the `BaseRichSpout` class, so you need to override BaseRichSpout's fail method in order to have replay capability in your application.

Comment: Excellent answer. Especially the tip about overriding BaseRichSpout's fail method. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Such replays of failed tuples should represent only a tiny proportion of the  overall tuple traffic, so the efficiency of this simple replay-from start policy is usually not a concern.

Supporting a "replay-from-error-step" would bring lot's of complexity since the location of errors are sometimes hard to determine and there would be a need to support "replay-elsewhere" in case the cluster node where the error happened is currently (or permanently) down. It would also slow down the execution of the whole traffic which would probably not be compensated by the efficiency gained on error handling (which, again, is assumed to be triggered rarely).

If you think this replay-from-start strategy would impact negatively your topology, try to break it down into several smaller ones separated by some persistent queuing system like Kafka.

Comment: Hi Svend, Does that mean between bolt to bolt replay is possible only if, we have reliable spout ? we really can't select reliability between just two  bolts and disable it remaining all places.

Comment: No, we can't select reliability between two bolts. We have to have reliable spouts in order to have replay capability in case of failures.